# How to get the redirect url?

Tags: php

I have a url for example like this:
http://facebook.com

I want to use a code to get the redirect link that it to will it out as follows: https://www.facebook.com then what to do?

I used this getOriginalURL decent but not as expected

```
function getOriginalURL($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        30);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpStatus = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    // if it's not a redirection (3XX), move along
    if ($httpStatus < 300 || $httpStatus >= 400)
        return $url;

    // look for a location: header to find the target URL
    if(preg_match('/location: (.*)/i', $result, $r)) {
        $location = trim($r[1]);

        // if the location is a relative URL, attempt to make it absolute
        if (preg_match('/^\/(.*)/', $location)) {
            $urlParts = parse_url($url);
            if ($urlParts['scheme'])
                $baseURL = $urlParts['scheme'].'://';

            if ($urlParts['host'])
                $baseURL .= $urlParts['host'];

            if ($urlParts['port'])
                $baseURL .= ':'.$urlParts['port'];

            return $baseURL.$location;
        }

        return $location;
    }
    return $url;

}
```

Comment: I think your code is working fine . Check with http://google.com

Comment: I run it turns out https://facebook.com results not out https://www.facebook.com as desired